# In JavaScript: Is a function parameter variable (at the moment of function declaration) equivalent to declaring a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, variable-declaration, function-parameter

I am currently studying variables and scope in JavaScript (from Kyle Simpson's YDKJS series), and I think I understand how the compiler "allocates memory for a variable `a`" in the appropriate scope if it encounters an explicit variable declaration such as `var a;`. My question is: In the case of function declarations, such as function `foo(a) {...};` if `a` hasn't been declared as a variable elsewhere yet, does the compiler "declare" that variable so it exists in the function's scope? Or is it that `a` "doesn't exist" until the function is called `foo(3);` and `a` assigned a value?

Sorry if this isn't relevant or if it is too basic. I am trying to fully grasp the idea of scope and variable declaration, and that came as something that I couldn't answer or find by doing some research.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regardless of existing outside the function - yes, the variable is created when you call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the named function parameter is a declaration just like `var a` is. When the scope (in this case the function scope) is entered, the memory is reserved for all declared variables. Then it is initialised with the passed argument (`3`) - or with `undefined` if no argument was passed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

`a` doesn't get assigned until the function is called. Your second guess is correct.